# ffmpeg: "stream specifier '' in filtergraph description matches no streams" during concatenation audio and video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate video and audio files, filling space between them with black frames or silence correspondingly.

I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i test/v/1.mkv -i test/v/2.mkv -i test/v/1.mka -i test/v/2.mka -filter_complex 'color=c=black:s=640x480:d=12ms[black0];
color=c=black:s=640x480:d=207725ms[black2];
aevalsrc=0:d=257495ms[silence1];
aevalsrc=0:d=114833ms[silence2];
[black0][0][black2][1][2][silence1][3][silence2]concat=n=8:v=1:a=1[v_out][a_out]' \
-map [v_out] -map [a_out] -c:v libvpx -c:a libopus result.webm
```

But I get the following error:

```
Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description matches no streams.
```

Full ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_9 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'test/v/1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2021-02-05T16:54:38.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:52.24, start: 0.637000, bitrate: 1922 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.83 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'test/v/2.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2021-02-05T16:58:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:07.19, start: 260.603000, bitrate: 1966 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.83 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
Input #2, matroska,webm, from 'test/v/1.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2021-02-05T16:55:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:02.44, start: 0.624000, bitrate: 80 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
Input #3, matroska,webm, from 'test/v/2.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2021-02-05T16:59:01.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:12.40, start: 260.561000, bitrate: 43 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description color=c=black:s=640x480:d=12ms[black0];
color=c=black:s=640x480:d=207725ms[black2];
aevalsrc=0:d=257495ms[silence1];
aevalsrc=0:d=114833ms[silence3];
[black0][0][black2][1][2][silence1][3][silence3]concat=n=8:v=1:a=1[v_out][a_out] matches no streams.
```

Video files do not contain audio.
What I'm doing wrong? Help please.

Comment: With `v=1:a=1` set, `n` refers to the number of paired video+audio segments, so no video or audio input can be fed standalone. They must be supplied in corresponding pairs: `[v1][a1][v2][a2]...`

Comment: In such case should I concatenate in two steps:
1) concat video and audio segments separately with v=1:a=0 and v=0:a=1 set correspondingly.
2) concat results of the previous step with v=1:a=1
?

Comment: No. You'll lose sync. You need to feed a silent audio stream if the video file doesn't have one.

Comment: In my situation audio and video offsets are calculated programmatically and gaps in each track are filled with silence or black frames, so all tracks have the same length and are synced. Just have checked separate concatenation, it works. After just need to combine one video and one audio streams.

But could you please clarify, what you mean? To feed a silent audio stream as an input source with "-i" option and then pass it to "concat"? By the way, what is faster in processing: have such stream as an input or generate silence in "filter_complex"?

Comment: Anyway thanks, Gyan.